# 2 identical Snow Leopard iMacs. One refreshes MCX records, one does not. Why?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, opendirectory, mcx

Identical model 2.4 GHz iMacs, using the same image, being imaged in the same exact way on the same subnet.  One will refresh and download group policy records (MCX) and the other does not.  Both bind to our OD server and will allow a network account to authenticate.  But one doesn't stick a single file in /Library/ManagedPreferences

I dont' think it's a hostname conflict, as both machines succesfully update their hostname upon first boot.

I can manually refresh the one that does, but I can't manually refresh the one that doesn't.  I've tried re-imaging these machines several times.  Older Leopard images did not exhibit this issue.

The image was built on another model iMac.  Snow Leopard 10.6.6  Running Snow Leopard on the OD server as well.

Comment: No two entities are ever exactly identical.

Comment: Why split irrelevant hairs?  They are identical model iMacs, most people understand that mass manufactured items aren't technically identical...

Answer (score 0):

Check the mac address (as in Ethernet) for the systems in the workgroup managers "Computers" section. You should have the address of the primary Ethernet interface in there.

[image]

Comment: Both have the correct mac address entered.  They are also both in the same computer group, so they should be inheriting the same records.  Yet only one is.  Odd.